# Existence of periodic orbits (non-linear systems)

Tags: surfaces, periodic-functions, nonlinear-system

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Use the Poincaré-Bendixson's criterion to show that the system has a periodic orbit
$$
\dot{x}_1 =x_2 \\
\dot{x}_2=-x_1+x_2-2(x_1+2x_2)x_2^2
$$

The unique equilibrium is (0,0), and the reduced Jacobian matrix
$$
\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1& 1
\end{matrix}
$$

And the eigenvalues $1\pm\frac{1}{2}i\sqrt{3}$ meaning the first part of the lemma is achieved.

However, I am unsure as how to do the the second part of the lemma which states "Every trajectory  starting in M stays in M for all future time". If I understand it correctly the term
$$
f(x)\cdot \nabla V(x)=\frac{\partial V}{\partial x_1}f_1(x) +\frac{\partial V}{\partial x_2}f_2(x)\leq0 
$$
I am not sure how to obtain $V(x)$ though. In my book they grab it out of the blue air for one example as $V(x)=x_1^2=x_2^2$ and $c>0$ and $V(x)=c$ on the surface.

Can you help me how to determine $V(x)$ and whether or not it has a periodic orbit?

Comment: Yes, how do I determine that for a system?

Comment: Still need help